# How change the default username and password for ArangoDB during a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nosql, arangodb

I want to know how to change or create a default username & password in the arangodb cluster while deploying in the Kubernetes.

I tried the below solution but, not working

```
env:
  - name: ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
    value: "newrootpassword"
  - name: ARANGO_USERNAME
    value: "newusername"
  - name: ARANGO_PASSWORD
    value: "newpassword"
```

my_arango.yml

```
apiVersion: "database.arangodb.com/v1"
kind: "ArangoDeployment"
metadata:
  name: "arangodb-cluster"
spec:
  metrics:
    mode: sidecar
    enabled: true
    image: 'arangodb/arangodb-exporter:0.1.8'
    tls: false
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '9101'
    prometheus.io/scrape_interval: '5s'
  mode: Cluster
  environment: Production
  tls:
    caSecretName: None
  agents:
    count: 3
    args:
      - --log.level=debug
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 500Mi
    storageClassName: nfs-csi
  dbservers:
    count: 3
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 500Mi
    storageClassName: nfs-csi
  coordinators:
    count: 3
  image: "arangodb/arangodb:3.10.3"
  env:
  - name: ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
    value: "pass"
```

Please give me a working solution to change the default password.

Thanks in advance,

Rajadurai M

Answer (score 0):

Please check this docs about bootstrapping the deployment with pre-defined root password: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/kubernetes/deployment-resource-reference/#specbootstrappasswordsecretnamesroot-string

In general, you should create a secret and then specify it in ArangoDeployment spec:

```
kubectl create secret generic arango-root-pwd --from-literal=password=<paste_your_password_here>
```

Then apply a patch for CR:

```
spec:
  bootstrap:
    passwordSecretNames:
      root: arango-root-pwd
```